# FFMPEG input 6 x 24 bit mono but output 5.1 16 bit

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, merge

I would like to create a 5.1 wav file from 6 mono. Those 6 mono files are 24 bit, but FFMPEG output a 16 bit 5.1. So I forced ffmpeg to transcode in 24 Bit with **-c:a pcm_s24le** as shown above :

```
'/Users/davincimp/Documents/ffmpeg/ffmpeg'  -i /Volumes/ARECA_IN/PROJETS/CITOYENNOBEL/SON_CITOYENNOBEL/191223_Mix_Nobel_DCP/191223_Mix_Citoyen_Nobel-DCP.L.wav -i /Volumes/ARECA_IN/PROJETS/CITOYENNOBEL/SON_CITOYENNOBEL/191223_Mix_Nobel_DCP/191223_Mix_Citoyen_Nobel-DCP.R.wav -i /Volumes/ARECA_IN/PROJETS/CITOYENNOBEL/SON_CITOYENNOBEL/191223_Mix_Nobel_DCP/191223_Mix_Citoyen_Nobel-DCP.C.wav -i /Volumes/ARECA_IN/PROJETS/CITOYENNOBEL/SON_CITOYENNOBEL/191223_Mix_Nobel_DCP/191223_Mix_Citoyen_Nobel-DCP.LFE.wav -i /Volumes/ARECA_IN/PROJETS/CITOYENNOBEL/SON_CITOYENNOBEL/191223_Mix_Nobel_DCP/191223_Mix_Citoyen_Nobel-DCP.Ls.wav -i /Volumes/ARECA_IN/PROJETS/CITOYENNOBEL/SON_CITOYENNOBEL/191223_Mix_Nobel_DCP/191223_Mix_Citoyen_Nobel-DCP.Rs.wav -c:a pcm_s24le -filter_complex '[0:a][1:a][2:a][3:a][4:a][5:a]join=inputs=6:channel_layout=5.1:map=0.0-FL|1.0-FR|2.0-FC|3.0-LFE|4.0-BL|5.0-BR[a]' -map '[a]' /Volumes/ARECA_IN/PROJETS/CITOYENNOBEL/SON_CITOYENNOBEL/191223_Mix_Nobel_DCP/CN4.wav
```

But I got this message : **Filesize 4621443998 invalid for wav, output file will be broken**

```
Output #0, wav, to '/Volumes/ARECA_IN/PROJETS/CITOYENNOBEL/SON_CITOYENNOBEL/191223_Mix_Nobel_DCP/CN4.wav':
  Metadata:
    ITCH            : Pro Tools
    originator_reference: au62Lxh4urQk
    ICRD            : 2019-12-23
    time_reference  : 172320000
    ISFT            : Lavf58.29.100
    Stream #0:0: Audio: pcm_s24le ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 48000 Hz, 5.1, s32, 6912 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.54.100 pcm_s24le
[wav @ 0x7faf65194600] Filesize 4621443998 invalid for wav, output file will be broken
size= 4513129kB time=01:29:08.89 bitrate=6912.0kbits/s speed= 418x    
video:0kB audio:4513129kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.000003%
```

Do you know to merge those 6 mono files into a 5.1 24bit ?

Best

Robin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Enable RF64

From [Wikipedia - WAV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WAV#Limitations):

> The WAV format is limited to files that are less than 4 GiB, because
>   of its use of a 32-bit unsigned integer to record the file size
>   header. Although this is equivalent to about 6.8 hours of CD-quality
>   audio (44.1 kHz, 16-bit stereo), it is sometimes necessary to exceed
>   this limit, especially when greater sampling rates, bit resolutions or
>   channel count are required. The W64 format was therefore created for
>   use in Sound Forge. Its 64-bit header allows for much longer recording
>   times. The RF64 format specified by the European Broadcasting Union
>   has also been created to solve this problem.

You can enable RF64 in `ffmpeg` with the `-rf64` output option. From `ffmpeg -h muxer=wav`:

```
  -rf64              <int>        E........ Use RF64 header rather than RIFF for large files. (from -1 to 1) (default never)
     auto                         E........ Write RF64 header if file grows large enough.
     always                       E........ Always write RF64 header regardless of file size.
     never                        E........ Never write RF64 header regardless of file size.
```

Example:

```
'/Users/davincimp/Documents/ffmpeg/ffmpeg'  -i /Volumes/ARECA_IN/PROJETS/CITOYENNOBEL/SON_CITOYENNOBEL/191223_Mix_Nobel_DCP/191223_Mix_Citoyen_Nobel-DCP.L.wav -i /Volumes/ARECA_IN/PROJETS/CITOYENNOBEL/SON_CITOYENNOBEL/191223_Mix_Nobel_DCP/191223_Mix_Citoyen_Nobel-DCP.R.wav -i /Volumes/ARECA_IN/PROJETS/CITOYENNOBEL/SON_CITOYENNOBEL/191223_Mix_Nobel_DCP/191223_Mix_Citoyen_Nobel-DCP.C.wav -i /Volumes/ARECA_IN/PROJETS/CITOYENNOBEL/SON_CITOYENNOBEL/191223_Mix_Nobel_DCP/191223_Mix_Citoyen_Nobel-DCP.LFE.wav -i /Volumes/ARECA_IN/PROJETS/CITOYENNOBEL/SON_CITOYENNOBEL/191223_Mix_Nobel_DCP/191223_Mix_Citoyen_Nobel-DCP.Ls.wav -i /Volumes/ARECA_IN/PROJETS/CITOYENNOBEL/SON_CITOYENNOBEL/191223_Mix_Nobel_DCP/191223_Mix_Citoyen_Nobel-DCP.Rs.wav -c:a pcm_s24le -filter_complex '[0:a][1:a][2:a][3:a][4:a][5:a]join=inputs=6:channel_layout=5.1:map=0.0-FL|1.0-FR|2.0-FC|3.0-LFE|4.0-BL|5.0-BR[a]' -map '[a]' -rf64 auto /Volumes/ARECA_IN/PROJETS/CITOYENNOBEL/SON_CITOYENNOBEL/191223_Mix_Nobel_DCP/CN4.wav
```

Note that the output will not be a typical WAV file so player support is not guaranteed.

## Or output a different container format

Alternatively, you can output to a different container format, such as `.mka`, if your workflow supports it.